# Remove same value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following associative array I wanna remove those ones that which have same value and keep one of theme(for example there is tow 124 value one of theme should be removed):

```
Array
        (
            [0] => 124
            [1] => 124
            [2] => 35
        )
```

Comment: How is your array associative?

Comment: This doesn't look like an associative array, it looks like an indexed array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) function

```
$array_unique = array_unique($array);
```

Results:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 124
        [2] => 35
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) method

For example :

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```